# A question about sublinear functionals

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Could you please give me hints may leads to prove the following:

*Let $X$ be a real vector space, $\,p_1,p_2:X\to\mathbb R\,$ be two [sublinear functionals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sublinear_function), and
$\,f:X\to\mathbb R\,$ be a linear functional satisfying
$$
f(x)\le p_1(x)+p_2(x), \quad\text{for all $\,x\in X$.}
$$
Prove that there exist two linear functionals $\,f_1,f_2:X\to\mathbb R$, such that
$\,f=f_1+f_2\,$ and $\,f_i(x)\le p_i(x),\,$ for $i\in\{1,2\}$ and $x\in X$.*

I think we should use Hahn-Banach Theorem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This has been answered here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1184199/prove-that-there-exist-linear-functionals-l-1-l-2-on-x